# Cache ~/.npm Directory in Jenkins Pipeline Running in Docker image

Tags: node.js, jenkins, node-modules, multibranch-pipeline

Currently I had Installed Jenkins in Kubernetes Cluster and Doing CD-CD With Multi-branch pipeline, For Pipeline I used my custom image where node.js and other Required setup is Installed.

Now I Want to Setup Caching to Speed-up the CI-CD, I had Done Research for the same and Implemented possible ways, but i want to setup ~/.npm directory to be cached...

Is There is any option that i can configure and cache ~/.npm directory.

I Gone through the documents https://simonplend.com/how-to-speed-up-npm-install-in-your-node-js-builds/ to cache the ~/.npm directory. Anyone can help here to cache the ~/.npm directory

Comment: did you figure out how to cache node_modules using Jenkins? I'm also looking for the answer

Comment: Hello @burns0907, Sorry for the late reply. 

Still i didn't Found any solutions For the same. If you Found any Solution then let me know Please.

Comment: I'm planning to define a custom agent template with Persistent Volume (EBS based- EFS is too expensive) for slave. Using this I can mount the volume install dependencies, cache and store them. @Ravi

Comment: Hi, @burns0907
There is a Jenkins Plugin to set up caching of any of their pipelines. You can use "Pipeline cache" and save your cache files to static storage providers like AWS S3.